Collapse of the AHSS for $E^*(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^n)$ for $E$ a complex-oriented ring spectrum
Denote by $\newcommand{\CP}{\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}}i_{n, m}\colon \CP^n \to \CP^m$, $n \leq m \leq \infty$ the canonical inclusion.
Let $E$ be a homotopy commutative ring spectrum and $t \in \tilde{E}^2(\CP^\infty)$ a complex orientation¹ of $E$, i.e. $i_{1, \infty}^*(t) = \Sigma^2 \eta \in \tilde{E}^2(\CP^1) = \tilde{E}^2(S^2)$, the two-fold suspension of the unit $\eta \in \pi_0(E)$ of $E$.
I am trying to follow a proof of Kochman (namely part of that of Proposition 4.3.2 in Bordism, Stable Homotopy and Adams Spectral Sequences, although beware that I'm not entirely following his notation) for the statement that $E^*(\CP^n) \cong (\pi_* E)[i^*_{n, \infty}(t)] / (i^*_{n, \infty}(t)^{n + 1})$.
The proof goes as follows: We consider the AHSS for $E^*(\CP^n)$,
$$
    E_2^{*, *} = H^*(\CP^n; \pi_* E) \cong H^*(\CP^n) \otimes \pi_* E \cong \mathbb{Z}[t'] / (t'^{n + 1}) \otimes \pi_* E \Rightarrow E^{* + *}(\CP^n)
$$
where $t' \in H^2(\CP^n)$ is a generator. Being careful with the signs, we may as well write $E_2^{*, *} \cong (\pi_* E)[t'] / (t'^{n + 1})$; so far, so good. Now Kochman claims that $t' \in E_2^{2, 0}$ is an eternal cycle representing $i^*_{n, \infty}(t) \in E^2(\CP^n)$, so the spectral sequence collapses to yield $E^*(\CP^n) \cong (\pi_* E)[i^*_{n, \infty}(t)] / (i^*_{n, \infty}(t)^{n + 1})$ as desired.
Those last statements are giving me some trouble: I guess to conclude that $t'$ is an eternal cycle one can consider the map of spectral sequences between that for $\CP^n$ and that for $\CP^1 = S^2$ induced by $i_{1, n}$, the latter of which obviously collapses at the $E_2$-page, and noting that $i_{1, n}^*$ takes $t'$ to the orientation class $t \in E^2(\CP^1)$ which is in particular non-zero.
I don't follow any further, however. Thus my question: Why does the argument imply that $t'$ identifies with $i^*_{n, \infty}(t) \in E^2(\CP^n)$ on the $E_\infty$-page, and how does the (ring) structure of $E^*(\CP^n)$ follow from the fact the spectral sequence collapses at the $E_2$-page? Is there some general result I am not aware of from which this follows?

¹Kochman additionally assumes that $\pi_* E$ is bounded below. I am very much hoping for an answer that doesn't require this additional assumption, but of course assume it if you must.
